# Cancel Page show event and return back or redirect in jQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I ran in to a problem while developing a mobile app using Phonegap & jQuery Mobile.

I've an entry condition to be checked everytime before a page is shown, say `page A`. If the condition goes false, i navigate the app to another page, say `page X`. I did that using the page event `pagebeforeshow`.

But my problem is that...

Even though i used the `pagebeforeshow` event, the page `page A` is getting shown. Ie; the `page A` is shown once and then the apps navigates to `page X`. I dont want this `page A` to be displayed if the condition is wrong. I mean, cancel the that page show event and move on to other page.

Hope you've got what i asked.

Why it is so? is there any other method through which i can accomplish my task perfectly.

Any kind of helps would be deeply appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use **`pagebeforeshow`** event in this case, that is one of the last page events to trigger. At that point second page is already created and ready to be shown. This must be done before second page is about to be created.

First take a look at my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, there you will find a list of page events during a transition from page one to page two. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Now about your problem, here's a code that you can use to fix your problem. It is using **`pagebeforechange`** event (which is a first event to trigger during a page transition):

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){  
    var to = data.toPage,
        from = data.options.fromPage;

    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
        if (from) from = '#' + from.attr('id');

        if (from === '#index' && to === '#second') {
            alert('Can not transition from #index to #second!');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // remove active status on a button, if transition was triggered with a button
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-focus ui-btn');;
        }  
    }
});
```

And here's a live **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3PhKZ/, you should click on a next button to trigger a page change.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i think this might help. but i got 1 doubt about this. ie; you've mentioned the code is using `pagebeforecreate`. But i could see only `pagebeforechange`.

Comment: thanks bro. thanks for your time & effort. it solved my issue. :)